# Is there a way to disable a dropdown to users while still being able to submit a form with the disabled dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dropdown that is disabled to the user. I want for the user to be able to press a button that changes the selected item to a different one. For example: from the 4th item in the dropdown to the 7th.

I've tried disabling the dropdown, but when I do that and submit the form, I get a PHP error saying `Undefined index: id`.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select id='id' name='id' autocomplete='none' disabled required>
        <option value='2'>apple</option>
        <option value='6'>banana</option>
        <option value='10'>orange</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
const options = dropdown.options;

for (let i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
    if (options[i].value === id) {
        dropdown.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

PHP (This line seems to be the one breaking):

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Why are you setting the selected index instead of the value directly?

Comment: I'm getting information from a database and displaying it in a dropdown and on the page. When the user clicks the edit button next to the part on the page, it changes the position in the dropdown that displays more information than what's on the page. This is to allow the user to modify the content of that item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution that suits my needs. It was kind of simple. I just enabled the dropdown when I submitted the form, and instantly disabled it again.

```
id.removeAttribute('disabled');
const data = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
id.setAttribute('disabled', '');
request.send(data);
```

Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't defined method and action in your form tag. By default, I think, the method is set to 'GET', so when checking 'POST' you'll run into your error.
Therefore, set "method='post'" (and best also an action, e.g. "action='/yourPageName.php') and see if that helps.

Comment: I am submitting with POST not GET through JavaScript. Here's the code for it: `request.open('POST', './update.php', true);`

Comment: Ok, so if that is the case, then I have some more comments:
- I wonder if you even need a form at all then... seems like mixing two approaches. Not really wrong, but could get confusing.
- I think we need to see the full javascript. In any case, I would suggest to check in the browser console how the submitted request looks like. 
- In any case, I would suggest to explicitly read the field with the javascript and include in the request.

Answer (score 0):

A disabled input field will be ignored when you submit the form. I would suggest creating a hidden input field of name="id" if you want the user to view the dropdown but not select it.

```html
<form>
    <select id='id' autocomplete='none' disabled required>
        <option value='2'>apple</option>
        <option value='6'>banana</option>
        <option value='10'>orange</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name='id' value="6" /> 
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That's how I originally did it, I wanted a cleaner way of doing it without a pseudo dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an hidden input with the id="id" and change the select id to "temp_id". Then, since you are making the request from javascript, you can just update the hidden field before making the request.

```
<select id='temp_id' autocomplete='none' disabled required>
<option value='2'>apple</option>
<option value='6'>banana</option>
<option value='10>orange</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
```

Then, on your javascript, just before you make the request, run the code:

```
document.getElementById("id").value = document.getElementById("temp_id").value;
```

Comment: That's how I originally did it, I wanted a cleaner way of doing it without a hidden input.

Comment: Well, another way is reading from javascript the value of the field and put it in the url of the request: request.open('POST', './update.php?id=' + document.getElementById("id").value, true); That way you can read the value in php using $_GET['id]